# How can I pair 2 data types together in python?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a list called pair

I want it to contain a pair of strings and boolean values like

`pair = [(a,True), (b,False), (c,False)]` and so on. I just found out about tuples and wanted to use them for this purpose but they're immutable which is a bummer because I have to add and remove data later. How else could I achieve this? Later, I'd like to process the pairs eg `if a is True: do this`

Comment: Use 2d list, lists are mutable.

Comment: what about dict?

Comment: @RaminNietzsche, dictionary is the best structure for this data.  But as I am not sure, if OP wants to change the first part of the tuples or not. If so, then dictionary will contain the same problem is tuple.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Your right, It's possible not work if OP want to change keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use lists if you need mutability:

```
pair = [[a,True], [b,False], [c,False]]
```

And then you can change items in this way:

```
pair[0][1] = False
```

Comment: You are not using `arrays`, you are using `list`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know we could do it like that

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Thanks I fixed that!

Comment: @Kasramvd, indexing a Python list is `O(1)` - in fact, indexing a Python list goes faster than indexing a Python dict.

Comment: @TimPeters Yes, indeed! I think I gave too much coffee to myself today lol. The expression `if a is` made me mix it with the `contains` operation :).

Comment: @TimPeters But besides that, since the OP wants to check the validation of the items like `if a is True` I think the most proper data structure still would be a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict`:

```
pari_dict = dict(pair)
if pari_dict[a]:
    #do this
```

Comment: If `a` is a list of pair items you can just call the `dict()` function on it. You don't need a dict comprehension.

Comment: @Kasramvd It's my fault :)

Comment: It's not a fault but its more Pythonic this way ;).